# how to add symbian^3 UID?

Tags: symbian, nokia, nokia-n8, pkg-file

My application is only targeted for Nokia N8 . Can some one please tell me how to add support for Nokia N8 only and displays error if other handsets try to install it. If someone can place the working code and name of the file that needs to be updated. i would be much obliged.

Many thanks in return.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is detailed in [this document](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/61ae01cb-3c34-47f6-843e-485d4f56409b/S60_Platform_Identification_Codes.html?cp=0308A&entry=s60idcodesArticle6CTA). In your package (PKG) file:

```
#{"DeviceSpecificApp"},(0x20000001),1,0,0
[0x20029A73], 0, 0, 0, {"Nokia N8 UID"}
```

Where `0x20000001` is your app UID.
If the resulting SIS is installed to any device other than the N8, the user will get a warning "*Application not compatible with phone. Continue anyway?*"

Comment: true i agree but i am using Symbian C++ (Carbide) with QT and the problem occurs when i use qmake as qmake adds the default platform ids itself. i have managed to edit the pro file and added the deployment section in that but still i am unable to remove default added device dependencies by Qmake. Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if it is QT only then you can also do this without hacking the .PRO file. In your .PRO:

```
symbian {     
    supported_platforms = "; Application that only supports N8" \
        "[0x20029A73],0,0,0,{\"Nokia N8 UID\"}"
    # Remove the default platform dependencies
    default_deployment.pkg_prerules -= pkg_platform_dependencies

    packageheader = "$${LITERAL_HASH}{\"MyAppName\"}, \ 
        (0x20000000), 0, 10, 0, TYPE=SA"

    # Add in the new platform dependencies
    sisInformation.pkg_prerules = packageheader supported_platforms 
}

DEPLOYMENT += sisInformation
```

Obviously you will need to replace '0x20000000' with your app UID, change the app name and put in the right platform UID